# Scaling textures on a gltfjsx import model

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm completely new to this, and I don't know how to scale my texture to make it look smaller. it is a seamless texture. The three methods that come from materials do work well but the ones that have to do with texture don't do anything, surely it will be silly, but I'm starting to program and I don't know how to do it.

```
<mesh geometry={nodes.BON_GRAVA.geometry} 
      material={materials.BON_GRAVA} 
      material-map={useTexture("Gravel_001_BaseColor.jpg")}(works)
      material-metalness={0.0} (works)
      material-roughness={1.0} (works)
      material-roughnessMap={useTexture("Gravel_001_Roughness.jpg")} (works)
      material-normalMap={useTexture("Gravel_001_Normal.jpg")} (works)
      material-aoMap={useTexture("Gravel_001_AmbientOcclusion.jpg")} (works)
```

This is me trying to do something, sorry

[image: screenshot of 3D model]

I've been trying .repeat, .offset, .wrapS but I don't know how the syntax for THREE methods works since it's a file gltfjsx + react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `useTexture` hook at the top, then you can modify the `Texture`'s (when the component mounts) with a `useEffect` hook: (be sure to set the `needsUpdate` flag to `true` on the `Texture` after any changes)

```
export function Component() {

   const color = useTexture("Gravel_001_BaseColor.jpg");
   const roughness = useTexture("Gravel_001_Roughness.jpg");
   const normal = useTexture("Gravel_001_Normal.jpg");
   const ao = useTexture("Gravel_001_AmbientOcclusion.jpg");

   useEffect(() => {
      color.repeat = new Vector2(1, 1);
      color.wrapS = RepeatWrapping;
      color.wrapT = RepeatWrapping;
      color.needsUpdate = true; // don't forget this!
   }, [color])

   return (
      <mesh
         geometry={nodes.BON_GRAVA.geometry} 
         material={materials.BON_GRAVA} 
         material-map={color}
         material-metalness={0.0}
         material-roughness={1.0}
         material-roughnessMap={roughness}
         material-normalMap={normal}
         material-aoMap={ao}
      />
   )

}
```

Comment: Thank you veeeeeery much!! I'm going to try this!!